# XML styles no effect at all?

Tags: android, xml

I'm relative new in this area and I'm following a YouTube tutorial for a basic calculator app.
But I noticed, that `style = "@styles/button_calculator"` is not working at all. It is applied to buttons and after compile I get this error: `Missing attribute: layout_height` (For every button), but it actually is in the style.

My goal is to get the same result as in the Tutorial. I searched a lot in the internet now...

- the styles.xml is in the folder `Resources/values`
- The xml code is the same as in the video ([site with code & Video](https://resocoder.com/2017/09/08/make-a-calculator-app-with-xamarin-android-1-code/))

  **++ See this image for overview:**
  [Image: how it looks vs how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG2gW.png) **++**

**Style XML: styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="button_calculator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:ScaleY">1</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">ButtonClick</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calculator_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:text="123" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        app:rowCount="5"
        app:columnCount="4">
        <Button
            style="@styles/button_calculator"
            app:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:text="DEL" />
        <Button
            style="@styles/button_calculator"
            android:text="7" />

        // ++ More Buttons here ++

        <Button
            style="@styles/button_calculator"
            android:text="+" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have to add height and width attributes in your button widget something like this <Button android: height="30dp" android: width="30dp"/>

Comment: Yeah, but when I do this, I can't control it with the style anymore

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `<resources>` starting tag in the Style XML. Your error itself is saying that the resource file is not compiled successfully.

**Replace your code with this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="button_calculator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:ScaleY">1</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">ButtonClick</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes right, but I have it in my code, so it's just a copy mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
change app from gridlayout to android

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:columnCount="4">
```

add android at layout_columnWeight

```
<style name="button_calculator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:ScaleY">1</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">ButtonClick</item>
  </style>
```

and at button  change app to android and styles to style

```
<Button
        style="@style/button_calculator"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:text="DEL" />
```

if not affected try to rebuild project
hope this help

Comment: Are u change @styles/button_calculator to @style/button_calculator at all button?

Comment: After i'm check your video link, this for xamarin right? If you won, you can rewrite this code then use auto complete for get right code, hope this help and solve you problem